# All pictures, documents missing after 2019-12-21 Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-update

I hope it's not too late, Dell Tech says it is.

I've been fine with everything about my 2016 Dell PC, so when Windows asked to update and said it would install the the next time I shut it down, I didn't think anything of shutting it down.

When I turned it on the next day, MOST of the icons on the desk to screen were gone and the same with the Task Bar. And ALL of my Documents are gone, ALL of the Downloads are gone I can't get into the settings so I can set it so that I don't have to keep entering a password every time I shut down and restart---I don't know why I even did that, I only did it about 3 weeks ago, I'm the only one that uses this pc so I really don't need a logon password.

Can anyone tell me if others are having the same problems? Oh, one more thing, my desktop personalization settings are gone!

How can I find those missing pictures and documents?

Comment: Do you have a backup?  Have you kept BIOS and Drivers up to date?  If no to the above, I think Dell is correct although I am not sure why. All our Lenovo machines update without a hitch to V1909 and three of my own including one on V2004 (Insider)

Comment: It sounds like you got logged in with a temporary profile. Usually your documents are still present in C:\Windows.old\Users or in C:\users.

Comment: How did you set up this password? Maybe you created a new account? Check under ` C:\Users\ ` and tell us how many users are in there.

Answer (score 0):

As @LPChip states, a new empty profile appears to have been created, but your files are likely still on the disk (HDD). BTW, more info would be helpful: What Windows version? Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `winver.exe` to get the exact information. Where do you keep your documents, on your local machine or in the cloud, e.g. OneDrive? What model PC?

However, try this. While the PC is running under the new account, [*sign out of Windows*](https://www.howtogeek.com/261775/how-to-log-out-in-windows-8-and-10/). Easiest might be to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> and select `Sign out`. Now, on the log-in screen, enter your usual user name, rather than that of the new profile. If that makes all your documents available, then just delete the unneeded new user.

If that does not immediately fix the issue, *save the files on the disk*. If you have an external HDD or SSD, or large USB flash drive, copy at least the files in the `C:\Users\[user name]` folder. But better yet, make a disk image. You might want technical help to do this, but here are the basics:

- Since you do not have access to your User[user name] folders while logged in as another, non-administrator, user, you'll need to boot from external media.
- Download a disk imaging program such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and install it on the PC.
- [Create rescue media](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW7/Creating+rescue+media), e.g. a boot USB, CD or DVD using the above program.
- Borrow or buy an external drive, a bit larger than that of the PC.
- Find out how to boot from the rescue disk... that depends on the PC model.
- Use the rescue media to copy the entire disk onto the external drive.

Now you can look at the data saved to the external drive, ["browse the image"](http://reflect.macrium.com/help/v5/how_to/restore/browse_files_in_backups.htm). Likely, all your files are there, though you may need to look around in `C:\Users\...`